# Cant build profile with user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

**User Model:**

```
has_one :profile
before_create :build_profile # Works when using form views
```

**Profile Model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

I have the `user_id` on the profiles table so all is set there.

I want to create a user with profile from **console**:

```
User.create!(....).build_profile(...)
```

I only get the user but no profile.

```
User.new(...).build_profile(...).save
#=> can't modify frozen Hash
```

How to go about doing this? I'm sure what I did was correct. Is devise causing an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed the same operation with minor changes and it works as expected.

```
User.create!(name: 'Test user', email: "testuser@gmail.com", password: "password").build_profile.save
```

Below queries were executed.

```
BEGIN
  User Exists (35.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE   (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'testuser@gmail.com' AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
 SQL (7.0ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Test user', 'testuser@gmail.com', '$2a$10$adX3zznn6R5G94WY5CtCZOHAVYZCXBD/ASDdyoDU7jl8P9RmRJUmC', '2016-12-01 13:41:07', '2016-12-01 13:41:07')
  (2.6ms)  COMMIT
  Profile Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = '43' LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `profiles` (`user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('43', '2016-12-01 13:41:07', '2016-12-01 13:41:07')
 (1.7ms)  COMMIT  => true
```

Below model code with minimal data.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :profile
    end
```

Profile model

```
    class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user  
    end
```

If devise would create an issue for you, it must throw an validation error in console while saving the user object.

Edit: profile migration file

```
   class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :profiles do |t|
        t.string :user_id
        t.string :Description

        t.timestamps null: false
       end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes but no `user_id` on profile. Thats my issue now.

Comment: Ohhhhh. You have to call `.save` with `.create!`?

Comment: yes, use this and it will work. i'll update my ans with profile migration file